# Unable to pass selected date value from html to controller in angular full calender

Tags: javascript, angular-calendar

I am using angular 1 and angular ui full calender.The calender is getting displayed.If i click on any date in the calender i want to pass the selected date value to controller.But i am unable to pass selected date value from html to controller.

Here is my html calender

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <mwl-calendar
         events = "events"
         view = "calendarView"
         current-day = "calendarDay"
         ng-model = "selectedDate"
         view-title = "calendarTitle"
         ng-click = "dayClick(selectedDate)"
         delete-event-html = "'<div class=\'btn btn-danger btn-sm margin-right-10 pull-right\'><i class=\'ti-close\'></i></div>'"
         edit-event-click = "eventEdited($event)"
         delete-event-click = "eventDeleted($event)"
         on-drill-down-click = "false"
         cell-modifier = "modifyCell(calendarCell)">
    </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var SalesCalenderController = function($scope, $rootScope,$filter,
    $http, $location,$route,$routeParams,SalesCalenderService)
     {
         $scope.calendarView = 'month';
         $scope.calendarDay = new Date();
         $scope.dayClick = function(selectedDate) 
         {
             alert(selectedDate);
         };
         $scope.modifyCell = function(calendarCell) {
             for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
                 if (moment(calendarCell.date).isSame(moment($scope.dates[i]), 'day'))
                     calendarCell.isCustom = true;
             };
         }
     }
```

But in alert i am getting undefined.Can anyone tell how to get the selected date value in controller?

Comment: can you post yoru full controller code with html

Comment: Because in the controller you should define this.selectedDate = new Date() otherwise it will always return undefined.

Comment: @Dipak i have posted my controller code

Comment: Where i have to put  this.selectedDate = new Date()? Is it inside dayClick function?

Comment: I am using only that much code for html

Comment: but some how the variable does not have defined that is a reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163579/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-sachin-hr).

Comment: i tried initializing variable but still didnt work

Comment: I would really very glad if you show your complete code of controller and view so it would get and idea what is an actual reason.

Comment: I have texted you in chat section

Comment: I referred this plunker for implementing http://embed.plnkr.co/UBtk38HnebOQInxJVIwG/